# How to perform filter on aggregation results in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elastic search index that contains a certain field on which I want to perform a wildcard query. The issue is that the field is duplicated in many docs hence I want to use aggregation first to get unique values for that field and then perform a wildcard query on top of that. Is there a way I can perform the query on aggregation results in elastic search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can find the results you need by [collapsing your search results](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html) rather than using your strategy of first obtaining the aggregation results and then running a wildcard query.

Adding a working example with index data (with the default mapping), search query and search result.

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "role": "example123",
    "number": 1
}

{
    "role": "example",
    "number": 2
}

{
    "role": "example",
    "number": 3
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "role": "example*"
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "role.keyword"         
  }                   
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "72724517",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "role": "example",
                    "number": 1
                },
                "fields": {
                    "role.keyword": [
                        "example"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "72724517",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "role": "example123",
                    "number": 1
                },
                "fields": {
                    "role.keyword": [
                        "example123"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
```